# How to check if widget value is "Acceptable"?

Tags: c++, qt, validation

I have a `QComboBox` with a validator associated to it:

```
QComboBox* cb = new QComboBox;
// ...
cb->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(0.0, 100.0, 2, this));
```

This widget is connected to a slot that gets executed when the entered value is changed (`currentTextChanged()`).

```
connect(cb, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),
        this, SLOT(onTextChanged(QString)));
```

In this configuration, the `onTextChanged()` is executed when the validator returns `Acceptable` or `Intermediate`. How can I execute the slot only when the value entered is  really valid (`Acceptable`). Or alternatively, how can I check the validation state in the `onTextChanged()` slot? (Oddly, I have noticed that `cb->validator()` seems to always return a `nullptr`.)

Comment: "I have noticed that le->validator() seems to always return a nullptr" le or cb? You can also keep the validator pointer in a member variable.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Question fixed!

Comment: Try setting the parent of `QDoubleValidator` to the `QComboBox cb` instead of `this`.

Comment: @RedX I just tried. But the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a new validator to your combobox:

```
QComboBox* cb = new QComboBox;
QDoubleValidator* validator = new QDoubleValidator(0.0, 100.0, 2, this);
cb->setValidator(validator);
```

Connect your signal/slot:

```
connect(cb, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),
        this, SLOT(onTextChanged(QString)));
```

In the slot, start by checking if the current text is valid:

```
int pos = cb->currentIndex();
const QDoubleValidator* validator = qobject_cast<const QDoubleValidator*>(cb->validator());
QValidator::State state = validator->validate(txt, pos);
if (state != QValidator::Acceptable)
   return;
```

Comment: Is there no way to access the validator from the ``QComboBox`` instance?

Comment: Yes, http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#validator See the last changes

Comment: But, as I mentionned in the question, ``validator()`` returns me a null pointer. In fact, it does so not only in the slot, but also when I check it right after setting the validator with ``cb->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(0.0, 100.0, 2, this));``.

Comment: When I try your solution, I get the following error at the qobject_cast line: "C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'const QObject *' to 'QDoubleValidator *'". This seems to confirm the null pointer issue. (I use MSVC2015.)

Comment: No crash, using MSVC 2013 and MinGW. Sorry, i dont compile the code, i have just post the answer. You have to use a const casting: const QDoubleValidator* validator = qobject_cast<const QDoubleValidator*>(cb->validator());

Comment: It compiles with const, but I now get a segmentation fault at the ``validate()`` line. Testing ``(validator == nullptr)`` just after the cast returns ``true``.